# Off-topic rules

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Why would this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084019/how-to-give-advice-to-co-worker-without-seeming-as-though-im-lecturing-him-clo(Mine) be closed. Do you not class working as a team, an integral part of being a software developer? A pure programming site maybe, but shouldn't software development be the whole process in developing software including working with team members, project planning etc.

Is the site a purely a technical site? Or is there gun happy users?

Comment: There is an area 51 suggestion for a site that deals with specifically these issues. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1959/consultant-client-team-relations. I should note. It's my own suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow is about programming/software development, not programmers/software developers. Things like team development, yes it is integral to software development, but it is also integral to several other professions as well. So it has nothing to do with programming/software development itself, even if it has to do with people who program.

Take me, who works in an engineering firm in the food industry as a programmer. Advice on how to give advice to coworkers would help me as an engineer and as a food worker just as well as it works for me as a programmer (moreso, actually, because until recently I was the only programmer anyway). The broadness of the scope makes it not unique to the programming/software development profession as a result, so it is off-topic.

Comment: It does say it's about programming and "Software Development". Usually software development has a bigger scope than just programming, such as this. However I believe some of the other replies has cleared up the issue.

Comment: @UK-AL Scope is larger but the heart of the post remains the same. To that end, I've updated my answer with a simple string replacement. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4):

From [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

#### What kind of questions should I not ask here?

> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

Also, it's a question that isn't unique to programming:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and
> enthusiast programmers, people who
> write code because they love it. We
> feel the best Stack Overflow questions
> have source code in them, but if your
> question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - **matters that are unique to the programming profession**
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly borderline, and I'm not sure which side of the line it should be on.

It is true that SO is aimed at technical programming questions, but does tolerate some questions that don't strictly fit. In the past they were more tolerated than they are now. It is also true that it depends on who sees the question as to whether it gets closed or not, but this sort of question is always likely to get closed. You could try rephrasing the question, but that might be too late now it's closed.

There is a proposed site on Area 51 [Not Programming Related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) where this question would be welcomed, but it's going to be a while before it gets off the ground.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see my name on the closers list, so I'll just tell you why I would have voted to close.

This question would be equally applicable to any other technical field.  It would work, almost unmodified, on an accountants' or doctors' site.  It is not specific to programmers or programming.  It isn't a bad question by any means, but it doesn't belong on SO.

It does affect programmers, but so do many other possible questions.  Shall we field questions on nutrition and exercise, which are also important to programmers?  After all, programmers eat and need some physical activity, just as they frequently need to work in offices and deal with co-workers.